# How to pass scope value to a <input> element `value` property

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

### I want to pass a scope value to a input type hidden, but not able to pass

I have one drop down list I want to pass the scope variable to the input type but its not working. In place of PremiumVal it should get 75

html

```
<input type="hidden" name="premium"
       value={{premiumVal}}
       onchange="save('atgb')">
<h1>{{premiumVal}}</h1>//its getting data
```

JS

```
$scope.premiumVal = response.data[0].premiumVal;//75
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

When the controller updates the scope, the change is not immediately propagated to the input `value` property. First the AngularJS browser event loop needs to update the `value` attrubute of the input. Then the browser event loop needs to update the `value` property based on the new `value` attribute.

```
app.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.premiumVal = "75";
  elem = document.getElementById("my-hidden");
  console.log("scope",$scope.premiumVal);
  console.log("attr.value",elem.attributes.value);
  console.log("elem.value",elem.value);
  $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
    //THESE ARE EXECUTED ON NEXT AngularJS framework tick
    console.log("$evalAsync attr",elem.attributes.value);
    console.log("$evalAsync elem",elem.value);
  })
  $timeout(function() {
    //THESE ARE EXECUTED ON NEXT browser tick
    console.log("$timeout attr",elem.attributes.value);
    console.log("$timeout elem",elem.value);
  })
})
```

The [$evalAsync](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync) function delays the `console.log` statement allowing the AngularJS event loop to update the *attribute* `value`.

The [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) functions delays the `console.log` statement allowing the browser event loop to update the *element* `value`.

Any code that needs to use the new values needs to be delayed appropriately.

[image]

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

### [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/9twDMYZMAYV3hEPuXrBD?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.premiumVal = "75";
  elem = document.getElementById("my-hidden");
  console.log("scope",$scope.premiumVal);            //scope 75
  //console.log("attr.value",elem.attributes.value);
  console.log("elem.value",elem.value);              //elem.value {{premiumVal}}
  $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
    //console.log("$evalAsync attr",elem.attributes.value);
    console.log("$evalAsync elem",elem.value);       //$evalAsync elem {{premiumVal}}
  })
  $timeout(function() {
    //console.log("$timeout attr",elem.attributes.value);
    console.log("$timeout elem",elem.value);         //$timeout elem 75
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input id="my-hidden" type="hidden" name="premium"
           value={{premiumVal}}>
    <br>
    <h1>{{premiumVal}}</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `{{}}` and use `ng-value` instead of `value`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="premium" ng-value="premiumVal" onchange="save('atgb')">
```

Comment: ng-value="premiumVal" , this is not working for me, but when i give ng-value="75" its working

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have an isolated scope being created somewhere within your template. This can be created by ngIf among other things. You might need the "magic dot."

```
$scope.info = {}
...
$scope.info.premiumVal = response.data[0].premiumVal;


<input type="hidden" name="premium" ng-value="info.premiumVal" onchange="save('atgb')">
```

Comment: The scope property hiding problem only occurs with two-way binding. The `ng-value` attributes is a one-way binding.